# redux app, where to store request object

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest, redux, es6-promise

I need to abort requests sometimes, to do that i need access to the request object (no ability to cancel promises yet in es6).
I have request related logic in a route related logic, so no components to store data. What is right way in terms of redux, should I need to use store, make some kind of publish/subscribe or add another global object?

Comment: What have you tried? I'd probably go with your store. Although I'm not sure I understand what you mean by _I have request related logic in a route related logic_

Comment: @Ursus I mean when location changes it calls dispatch which get an action which starts this requests. Is it realy good idea to put requests to store - as I understand store data should be immutable but request object will change itself (after success for example)

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. You're correct, you shouldn't put requests in store. I'd just create a new reducer file, say `requests.js` (as well as a corresponding action file) and then built the request object there.

Comment: My question is where to store this request objects (as I need to abort them) - Do you mean requests.js module scope?

Comment: I'm still confused. How would you go about "aborting" requests? Also are you using any middleware?

Comment: The only way to abort request is (as I understand) is call reqObject.abort() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort
Thats why I need direct access to the request object (or this can be avoided with kind of listener on request object which will run abort method itself, but I think this pub/sub implementation are not good in terms of redux)
Yes, in this project some custom middleware are used.

Comment: Right. When you dispatch the action that triggers the request, you should get back a XMLHttpRequest object, which you can access directly. So, the action seems to me the natural place where to do that.

Comment: Abort operation can be required later - for example in 2 seconds after request started, so I need to store request for this time (actually request wrapped with a promise, but promises is not cancellable in es6)

Comment: OK, then I think your best bet is adding a new global object for requests.